# Get the local ip address with unix sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, network-programming

I am programming a simple UDP client server chat to get a little more familiar with network programming. Now to make it easier for the user to see what the servers IP address is (so the user can type it into the client to connect). That's why I would like the server to display its own local IP address.

This is my code: **(edited code to handle multiple IP's)**

```
// get the hostname of the server
char hostname[128];
if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == -1) {
    std::cout << "Could not get the hostname of the server. Error: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo hints, *serverInfo, *p;

std::memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use AF_INET (IPv4) or AF_INET6 (IPv6) to force version
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

// try to get information about our hostname
int rv;
if ((rv = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &serverInfo)) != 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to get information about the host \"" << hostname << "\". Error: " << gai_strerror(rv) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::cout << "IP addresses for " << hostname << ":" << std::endl;

// iterate over all the infos we got and try to extract the IP address
for(p = serverInfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    char serverIPAddress[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    void *addr;
    std::string ipVersion;

    // get the pointer to the address itself,
    // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
    if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
        ipVersion = "IPv4";
    } else { // IPv6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
        ipVersion = "IPv6";
    }

    // take the IP address of our hostname and convert it into a readable format
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, serverIPAddress, sizeof(serverIPAddress));
    std::cout << "  " << ipVersion << ": " << serverIPAddress << std::endl;
}

freeaddrinfo(serverInfo); // free the linked list
```

It works, but it doesn't display the correct IP address. Everytime I run it there is a different IP being displayed and it's not the correct one. As I said I am still learning about network programming, so I don't know why that is. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo, thanks to the advice I got here, I changed my approach and instead of trying to resolve the hostname of my machine to an IP address, I am now simply listing all the network interfaces and their IP addresses.

Here is my code:

```
// get the hostname of the server
char hostname[128];
if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == -1) {
    std::cout << "Could not get the hostname of the server. Error: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::cout << "IP addresses for " << hostname << ":" << std::endl << std::endl;

struct ifaddrs *networkInterfaceList, *p;

getifaddrs (&networkInterfaceList); // get information about the network interfaces

// iterate over all the network interfaces we got and try to extract their IP address
for (p = networkInterfaceList; p != NULL; p = p->ifa_next) {
    char serverIPAddress[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    void *addr;
    std::string ipVersion;

    // get the pointer to the address itself,
    // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
    if (p->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ifa_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
        ipVersion = "IPv4";
    } else { // IPv6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ifa_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
        ipVersion = "IPv6";
    }

    // take the IP address of our hostname and convert it into a readable format
    inet_ntop(p->ifa_addr->sa_family, addr, serverIPAddress, sizeof(serverIPAddress));

    // sometime the IP address is empty so only print if there is one
    if (std::strlen(serverIPAddress) > 0)
        std::cout << "Interface: " << std::setw(6) << std::left << p->ifa_name << " " << ipVersion << ": " << serverIPAddress << std::endl;
}

freeifaddrs(networkInterfaceList); // free the linked list
```

Just in case somebody else is trying something similar.

Also in case somebody is interested here is the chat repo: https://github.com/Foaly/Chat

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get your "global" IP address like this, only the local one. In order for the client to connect to you, it needs the global IP address, which is visible from the Internet, i.e. your gateway's (router's) IP. This is because your router translates your computer's IP address to a globally visible one and stores it in a table, so that incoming connections can be correctly routed to the correct sub-network. This is called *NAT*ing (find out more about **NAT** [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)).

If you want a client to connect to you **explicitly**, you need to give them your router's IP address (use command-line tools for this, depending on your OS) and configure port-forwarding so that the router will automatically forward the packets arriving on (IP_router, port_router) to (IP_host, port_host). This is done in the router's config panel. Depending on your router, this will be found somewhere in the menus. You can connect to your router by typing something like `192.068.0.1`, or `192.168.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
But like I said in the original question, I only want to get the my local IP address. The chat client is really really simple and only supposed to work in a local network (like my universities or my network at home).

Comment: OK. If it's only local, this can be done in several ways. Your client could broadcast a UDP discovery packet on the network aiming at the specific port of your client (eg. 987654), the server listening on some machine on the this port will establish the TCP connection using the discovery packet's source (IP, port) information.

Another way is to simply use `ipconfig` to lookup your IP address, if you don't want to go through all the above.

Comment: Ah now we are on the same page :) I basically just want what `ipconfig` does. So when I open up a server it says : `Welcome! This server is reachable under the IP: x.x.x.x` Then I can go over to another machine, open a client and type the IP address in. It's supposed to be a convenient functionallity so the don't have to call `ipconfig` everytime I start a server (my university PCs don't have `ipconfig` installed for example...)

Comment: That will usually not be possible, since your machine might have more than 1 network interface. To enumerate your network interfaces, use the algorithm posted above by **myk**. Then you can scroll through the network interfaces and select the one that you know is your network card.

Comment: Hmm I see. I guess I will go with listing all the network interfaces then. Just out of curiosity, shouldn't `getaddrinfo` return a list if there is more than one interface?

Comment: It does: "`getaddrinfo()` returns one or more `addrinfo` structures". See the `getaddrinfo()` man pages: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo

Comment: That is weird... Because for me it only returns one entry (127.0.1.1) while when I list my network adapters it returns 3 entrys and the one above is not mentioned, but the server is still reachable under said IP... I'm starting to think there is something that I haven't understood yet.

I updated my code to handle multiple `addrinfo` structures.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use `gethostbyname` and enumerate through the `hostent` `h_addr_list`... on Linux you can create a temporary socket and use `ioctl` on `SIOCGIFCONF` and enumerate through the interfaces.

Comment: You have to be careful using `gethostbyname()` in this manner. There are ways it can return wrong results. It is better to use `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead. On Linux, use `getifaddrs()` instead. `SIOCGIFCONF` only supports IPv4, whereas `getifaddrs()` supports both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  What kinds of situations would I get wrong results with `gethostbyname`?  Wondering if it warrants me reviewing the code there...

Comment: Using `gethostname()` and `gethostbyname()` may not always return just the machine's IP addresses. Technically speaking, they will return the local hostname, and then return the address(es) to which that hostname resolves. It is possible for a machine to (a) be configured such that its name does not resolve to an IP, or (b) be configured such that its name resolves to multiple IPs, only one of which belongs to the local machine. Using platform-specific APIs that directly enumerate the local network interfaces, like `GetAdapters(Info|Addresses)()` and `getifaddrs()`, avoids that pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get a Vector of the IP addresses of this computer
std::vector<std::string> getIPAddresses() {

    std::vector<std::string> IPAddresses;
    int TempAddress = 0;
    char* TempIPAddress = (char*) malloc(16);

    ifaddrs* ifap = NULL;   //Head of the interface address linked list

    if (getifaddrs(&ifap) == 0 && ifap != NULL) {

        //Get another pointer to move down the linked list
        ifaddrs* current = ifap;

        //Move down the linked list until we get to a NULL pointer
        while (current != NULL) {

            //Create a pointer of the correct type to work with
            const sockaddr_in* interfaceAddress = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr_in*>(current->ifa_addr);

            if (current->ifa_addr != NULL) {
                if (current->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                    //printf("%s:", current->ifa_name);
                    if (interfaceAddress != NULL) {
                        TempAddress = ntohl(interfaceAddress->sin_addr.s_addr);
                        sprintf(TempIPAddress, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (TempAddress >> 24) & 0xFF, (TempAddress >> 16) & 0xFF,
                               (TempAddress >> 8) & 0xFF, TempAddress & 0xFF);
                        //Don't include the lookback address
                        if (strcmp(TempIPAddress, "127.0.0.1") != 0) {
                            IPAddresses.push_back(std::string(TempIPAddress));
                        }
                        //printf("%s\n", TempIPAddress);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Move to the next node in the linked-list
            current = current->ifa_next;
        }

        //Release the interface memory
        freeifaddrs(ifap);
        ifap = NULL;
    }

    return IPAddresses;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the end of your code, you have misused the data structure sockaddr_in.
The line:

```
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(serverInfo->ai_addr), serverIPAddress, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

should be replaced with:

```
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)serverInfo->ai_addr;
void *addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr, serverIPAddress, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Comment: Indeed! That makes sense. I adapted my code to handle that correctly and also to handle multiple `addrinfo` being returned from `getaddrinfo`. But the only thing I get is 127.0.1.1 (which is not my loopback) but not my local IP Address.